# Concatenate csv column to string and print specific value

Tags: python

I have a csv file contains three columns: date, time and temperature.

Now I have the following code and need to concatenate date, time and temperature in a temporary string and append the temporary string into an array that holds values where temperature > 80, and print the result.

```
import csv
data_array = []
output = []

with open("temp.csv") as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    next(csv_reader, None)
    for row in csv_reader:
        data_array.append({"date": row[0], "time": row[1], "temp": float(row[2])})
#create an array of dictionary to put related data together; convert the temperature to float.
for item in data_array:
    if item['temp'] > 80:

        output.append(item)

print(output)
```

I can only print a dictionary of those items but how can I concatenate items and print a result? Shouldn't I use dictionary?

Comment: I'm confused what your expected output would look like. Could you post a sample?

Comment: Sure. like{
    [‘1/2/2018 10:00 AM’, 65.5], 
    [1/2/2018 11:00 AM’, 67.3], 
    … 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a temporary list of dicts. Simply build a list of concatenated date and time and the temperature and append the list to the output list when the temperature is greater than 80 directly withint the loop that iterates through the CSV reader:

```
with open("temp.csv") as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    next(csv_reader, None)
    for date, time, temperature in csv_reader:
        temperature = float(temperature)
        if temperature > 80:
            output.append([' '.join((date, time)), temperature])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. My second day of python so don't now lots of simple stuff yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
output.append(item)
```

To

```
output.append(['{} {}'.format(item['date'], item['time']), item['temp']])
```